# Excel - Formula recalculation scenario

Tags: microsoft-excel

1. I understand the `if` function does short-circuiting (i.e. to evaluate/calculate only either the TRUE/FALSE part of the formula, and not both, depending on the result of the criteria)
2. However, as I understand, a *cell* is recalculated when a range/cell that it refers to is changed.

As I see it, both 1 & 2 above have some common ground with respect to recalculation and wish to understand how Excel is designed to operate.

Here goes a sample formula,

`A1:=IF(criteriaX, Range1_Op, Range2_Op)`

Now,

1. I change a cell in `Range2`
2. `criteriaX` evaluates to TRUE

In this scenario, is the cell `A1` flagged by Excel for recalculation?

I have the above-like formula in about 1000+ cells and looking to improve the speed of these calculations.

NOTE: criteriaX might return `FALSE` as well in a bunch of other cells

---

EDIT: Also, if I have these formulae in an *Excel Table* will it slow down the calculations

Comment: What have you tried to answer your own question?  See [How to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)  also see this Microsoft article [Excel Recalculation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation)

Comment: How long does the recalculation currently take?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad More than 15 seconds. And, this worksheet is something I constantly add data into. So, the recalculation fires up with expanding ranges (courtesy Excel Tables)

Comment: Pretty sure the table makes no difference. I have a feeling the dependency tree will flag cell A1 for recalculation if any cell in Range1 or Range2 is changed, otherwise every time the cell was recalculated it would also have to update the dependency tree based on the outcome of the condition. It is likely that this would be less efficient than recalculating in any case.